# Sumar algunos elementos de una tupla en Python

Tags: python, lista, tuplas, itertools

Tengo este código el cual agrupa por el primer elemento:

```
from itertools import groupby
seleccion=[('201', 480, 4202), ('201', 240, 1988), ('306', 360, 3186)]
if seleccion:
    dic = {}
    f = lambda x: x[0]
    for key, group in groupby(sorted(seleccion, key=f), f):
        dic[key] = list(group)
    print(dic)
```

Al imprimirlo obtengo lo siguiente:

```
{'201': [('201', 480, 4202), ('201', 240, 1988)], '306': [('306', 360, 3186)]}
```

Lo que necesito es ahora poder sumar los 480 + 240 y los 4202 + 1988, para que me de como resultado

```
('201', 720, 6190)
('306', 360, 3186)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No necesitas construir el diccionario intermedio para hacer eso, puedes hacerlo directamente al iterar por los grupos:

```
result = []
seleccion=[('201', 480, 4202), ('201', 240, 1988), ('306', 360, 3186)]
if seleccion:
    f = lambda x: x[0]
    for key, group in groupby(sorted(seleccion, key=f), f):
        result.append((key, *map(sum, zip(*(l[1:] for l in group)))))
    print(result)
```

Sale:

```
[('201', 720, 6190), ('306', 360, 3186)]
```

Si quieres hacerlo a partir del diccionario que ya tienes creado sería similar:

```
result = []
for key, group in dic.items():
    result.append((key, *map(sum, zip(*(l[1:] for l in group)))))
```

La sintaxis es fea y torpe, pero fue por querer hacerlo todo en una sola línea usando programación funcional. Si quieres puede "desenrollarse" en una serie de bucles más convencionales:

```
result = []
for key, group in dic.items():
  numeros = []
  r = [key]
  for l in group:
    numeros.append(l[1:])
  for serie in zip(*numeros):
    suma = sum(serie)
    r.append(suma)
  result.append(tuple(r))
```

### Explicación de la linea "magica"

La línea que hace todas las sumas:

```
  result.append((key, *map(sum, zip(*(l[1:] for l in group)))))
```

merece una explicación un poco más detallada. Lo que hace es añadir a la lista `result` una tupla (por lo que se le pasa a `.append()` lleva otro par de paréntesis). Esa tupla tiene como primer elemento la `key`, y los restantes elementos son el *desempaquetado* de lo que retorne `map`.

Esto quiere decir que si `map` retorna por ejemplo dos elementos de valores 720 y 6190, la línea anterior haría `result.append((key, 720,  6190))`

Ahora ¿qué hace `map`? Lo que hace es aplicar una función que le pasemos como primer parámetro (en este caso `sum`) a todos los elementos del iterable que le pasemos como segundo parámetro. Devuelve otro iterable con los resultados. Por ejemplo, la invocación `map(sum, [(480, 240), ( 4202, 1988)])` devolvería la secuencia `720, 6190`, pues aplica `sum()` a cada una de las tuplas del iterable.

El primer parámetro que pasamos a `map` está claro. Pasamos `sum` porque queremos sumar cosas. Y ¿qué le estamos pasando como segundo parámetro a `map()`? Pues el resultado de aplicar `zip()`.

`zip()` es una función que recibe varios iterables y los va "emparejando". Si por ejemplo le pasamos a `zip()` los siguientes parámetros: `zip([480, 4202], [240, 1988])` entonces `zip()` junta todos los primeros elementos, después todos los segundos, por lo que va retornando la secuencia `(480, 240)`, `(4202, 1988)`.

Así que a `zip()` tenemos que pasarle varios parámetros. Por eso hay un `*` en la expresión, para *desempaquetar* una secuencia y convertir cada elemento en un parámetro separado. Y llegamos por fin al núcleo:
`l[1:] for l in group`

Eso toma cada lista dentro de `group` y le quita el primer elemento (que era la cadena) dejando solo los otros dos.

Así que reconstruyamos qué ocurre, ahora de dentro a fuera, cuando `group` es el primer grupo `[('201', 480, 4202), ('201', 240, 1988)]`

- `l[1:] for l in group` genera la secuencia `(480, 4202), (240, 1988)`
- Esa secuencia se convierte con el `*` en una serie de argumentos que se le pasan a `zip` el cual por tanto recibe `zip((480, 4202), (240, 1988))`
- Zip retorna otra secuencia emparejando todos los primeros elementos, después todos los segundos, etc. Por tanto retorna la secuencia `(480, 240), (4202, 1988)`
- Esa secuencia es el segundo parámetro de `map()`, de modo que la invocación de `sum()` equivale a: `map(sum, [(480, 240), (4202, 1988)])`
- `map()` va invocando `sum` para cada elemento de la secuencia, por lo que invocará `sum((480, 240))` y después `sum((4202, 1988))`, y genera otro iterable con los resultados. Por tanto generará un iterable que contendrá `720, 6190`
- Ese iterable se desempaqueta (porque hay un `*` delante de `map`) y así se genera la tupla que finalmente se pasará al `.append()`. En este caso recibirá los parámetros `.append(('201', 720, 6190))` que se guardará en la lista `resultados.

Buf!